# Video stream played too fast if HTTP Live Stream starts at the beginning

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, transcoding

Bit of an odd problem this, I'm building a server that Transcodes video and streams it to the WiiU.

The WiiU seems to have quite good support of HTTP Live Streams, but I'm running into a problem where the video stream will play about x3 faster than intended (the audio plays at normal rate).

I'd figure something was up with my ffmpeg command, but if I let the stream run (so the first segment grabbed by the WiiU isn't actually the first segment) before I actually connect to it the WiiU will play the video at the normal rate!

Here's the ffmpeg command I've been using (post-shlex breakup):

`['./ffmpeg', '-threads', '4', '-i', '../../Torrents/Breaking.Bad.S05E02.720p.HDTV.x264-ORENJI.mkv', '-map', '0', '-codec:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'superfast', '-codec:a', 'aac', '-ac', '2', '-crf', '23', '-flags', '-global_header', '-strict', 'experimental', '-f', 'segment', '-segment_list', 'playlist.m3u8', '-segment_list_flags', '+live', '-segment_time', '10', 'tmp/out%03d.ts']`

And the first few lines of the .m3u8:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOWCACHE:1
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:11.761756,
tmp/out000.ts
#EXTINF:8.591911,
tmp/out001.ts
#EXTINF:18.810467,
tmp/out002.ts
#EXTINF:7.841178,
...
```

(PS, VLC + Safari can play the stream file.)

Any ideas what's happening?

If it's a bug I have to work around rather than solve, any recommendations?

Just tested starting the stream with a dummy.ts file (knowing it wont be read as the wiiu only reads the last 3 files in live mode) it still had the speedup, implying that it's something ffmpeg is putting in the first file (and only the first file...)

Comment: Try adding `-re` as an input option although I'm unsure if this is a good suggestion. You can omit `-threads` since the default is to automatically determine an appropriate number (frame based threads: 1.5 * logical processors, rounded down)--unless you particularly want a value of `4`.

Comment: -re just slows down the transcode with no effect on the framerate of the output. Have now omitted threads (didn't seem to have much effect anyway)

Comment: Did you change ffmpeg versions or something recently? THis may seem funny but can you try transcoding a non mkv?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `'-preset', 'fast',` or `'medium'` ?

Comment: Doesn't fix it, when outputting a http live stream it's the clients responsibility to play the files at the right speed unlike normal streams.

Comment: Does it happen on all player?